# MenuBarItems in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am playing with mvvm and wpf. Now, my total solution is MVVM-friendly. The only thing i have put in code behind is the "make new product" & close buttons on the mainview.

Now im adding a menubar, and i was wondering if i can put these "make new product" & close Items in code behind, or is this a no go?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using MVVM, the answer is no. Don't use code behind for things that belong in the view model (VM).

Comment: you should probably use routed commands in your view model however if close item is like a window close you can handle it as an event in the code behind

Answer (score 4):

The MVVM way to do it is commands. You can consider them as proxies between your declarative XAML and imperative VM.

1. Create CreateNewProductCommand, implementing ICommand.
2. Create a handler for the command performing the actual work as part of ICommand interface implementation (conventionally called On*** - OnCreateNewProductCommand) (you may want to pass paramteres for edit, which is supported by the interface too).
3. Expose your command as property of your VM.
4. Bind your menu item command (it'll likely have it, just search for properties containing Command) property to that command using standard binding syntax pointing to the relevant property created at a previous step.

This is not the only way to do it. There're more advanced techniques based on interactions/behaviors etc. Some of them would allow you to bypass command creation and bind your UI element event directly to the executable member of your VM.