# ICommand help to replace button events

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, icommand

I am just after some information regarding ICommands,

On my WPF application, I have onClick events that adds to a ObservableCollection. So (ObservableCollection.Add()

However, I have 2 similar events to add to a collection also. So I hear I could use the ICommand interface to "execute" for adding/Editing/Removing etc, so I don't need these separate events.

Can someone provide me a example of how I can do this in MVVM. (All adds are in my ViewModel)

Thanks

Comment: Here's my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690615/menubaritems-in-mvvm/22691104#22691104

Comment: Thanks, look decent. However, if I want to add using a Command, do I use the <Button command> reference? That's the bit I need to know more on.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it should be as simple as binding your MV command to Command property of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the "RelayCommand" - it's a common implementation of an ICommand that will simplify your view-model code, allowing you to specify delegates for the ICommand's "Execute" and "CanExecute" methods. You'll find plenty of implementations on the web, but this is the one I use:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        this._execute = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this._canExecute == null || this._canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

In your VM, expose a command like this:-

```
public ICommand FooCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_fooCommand == null)
        {
            _fooCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteFooCommand, CanDoFooCommand);
        }
        return _fooCommand;
    }
}

private void ExecuteFooCommand(object commandParameter)
{
    // Code to execute the command.
}

private bool CanDoFooCommand()
{
    // Code that indicates whether the command can be executed.
    // This will manifest itself in the view by enabling/disabling the button.
}
```

As the RelayCommand ctr parameters are delegates, you can of course do stuff like this:-

```
new RelayCommand(o => { // do something }, o => true);
```

Finally, bind your command to your view button:-

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding FooCommand}" ... />
```

You can also pass parameters to the command delegate:-

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding FooCommand}" CommandParamter="123" />
```

(Written out from memory so may not be 100% syntactically correct!)

*Going one step further...*

To simplify things even more, I use a dynamic property to expose VM commands to the view. In my VM base class I have the following property:-

```
    public dynamic Commands
    {
        get
        {
            return _commands;
        }
    }
```

Then in a VM's constructor I can create all of its commands like this:-

```
Commands.FooCommand = new RelayCommand(.....
Commands.BarCommand = ..etc..
```

In my XAML I bind commands like this:- `Command={Binding Commands.FooCommand}`.
It's a timesaver as it just means I can hang as many commands off of a single property as I want, rather than expose each one as a separate property as in my earlier example.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, very informative. Do I declare one Property of ICommand in the VM? And use the the CommandParameter to execute the events I have in my VM? Thanks

Comment: Typically you'll expose a separate ICommand property for each button in your view, but "it depends" on what your buttons are doing. As an example, you might have a series of buttons for playing different sounds - here you could expose a single "PlaySound" ICommand in your VM, and use the CommandParameter on each button to specify the name of the wav file to play.

Comment: @user3428422 if you provide a CommandParameter in the XAML, when the command is executed (by clicking the button), the paramater value gets passed to the RelayCommand's execution delegate (the "ExecuteFooCommand" method in the above example).